# Как игнорировать NULL в ELSE

Tags: mysql, sql, if, null, case

Всем привет. Использую следующий запрос, и хочу возвращать только значения TRUE при использовании CASE, но все что FALSE возвращается со значением NULL, а мне эти строки не нужны. Есть какое-нибудь решение данного вопроса в конструкции CASE не прибегая ко вложенным запросам?

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title "Название сети",
       CASE WHEN t2.company_id = 7777 THEN count(distinct t2.company_id) END AS 'Количество компаний в сети',
       CASE WHEN t2.company_id = 7777 THEN count(distinct t3.user_id) END AS 'Количество юзеров в сети'
from table_2 t2
join table_3 t3 on t2.group_id = t3.group_id
join table_1 t1 on t2.group_id = t1.id
group by t2.group_id
order by 3 desc ,4 desc
```

Comment: Где здесь Else? Можете детализировать вопрос с примером данных?

Comment: Запрос тупо неверный. Синтаксически. Включите ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY и убедитесь. И не надо радоваться, что при текущих настройках он выполняется - запрос неверен логически, ошибочность синтаксиса лишь следствие кривой логики.

Comment: @SwaD, при отсутствии явного ELSE у CASE всегда есть неявный ELSE NULL. Это прописано в стандарте

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы в выборку не попадали строки, не удовлетворяющие условию WHEN нужно сделать так, чтоб в неё попадали только удовлетворяющие. Этот отсев нужно сделать при помощи конструкции WHERE.

В приведённом запросе добавить `where t2.company_id = 7777`